# ThreadPoolExecutor is not monkey-patched to the Gevent's one

Tags: python, flask, threadpool, gevent, monkeypatching

I want to execute some long-lived tasks asynchronously by submitting them into a thread pool.

However, gevent's monkey patching does not do the trick for `from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor`. (It should replace the built-in thread pool to `gevent.threadpool.ThreadPoolExecutor`)

Here is my `main.py`:

```py
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
# from gevent.threadpool import ThreadPoolExecutor
from flask import Flask

app = Flask("playground")

@app.route("/test")
def test_route():
    ThreadPoolExecutor().submit(is_prime, 2147483647)
    return "ok"

def is_prime(n):
    for i in range(2, n):
        if n % i == 0:
            print(f"{n} is NOT a prime number")
            return
    print(f"{n} is a prime number!!")
```

- Run the application by `gunicorn --timeout=5 --worker-class=gevent main:app`
- Trigger the API by `curl localhost:8000/test`

My is-prime job will be interrupted due to gevent worker timeout (5 seconds).

Everything will be fine when I uncomment the second line.

Am I missing something with the gevent's monkey patching? Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: have you tried setting this variable https://www.gevent.org/configuration.html#gevent._config.Config.threadpool

Comment: @gold_cy I checked the configuration. Its value is `<class 'gevent.threadpool.ThreadPool'>`. (same as default)